# Exit animation does not play after Children in framer motion

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I have 3 states for my navbar component, open, closed and exit. Exit animation with `when: "afterChildren"` works if i set my `exit="closed"`. However if i set my `exit="exit"` it doesn't wait for the children to finish animating.

```
<motion.div
  id="mobile-menu"
  className="fixed inset-0 w-full h-[90vh] mt-[10vh] bg-gray-900 z-40 p-20 flex flex-col gap-8 align-top"
  variants={{
    open: {
      y: "0%",
      transition: {
        bounce: "0",
        when: "beforeChildren",
        staggerChildren: 0.5,
      },
    },
    closed: {
      y: "-100%",
      transition: {
        bounce: "0",
        when: "afterChildren",
      },
    },
    exit: {
      x: "100%",
      transition: {
        bounce: "0",
        when: "afterChildren",
      },
    },
  }}
  initial="closed"
  animate="open"
  exit="exit"
>
  {navLinks.map((item) => {
    return (
      <motion.a
        className="text-[#FAFAFA] font-bold text-2xl hover:text-gray-500 cursor-pointer w-fit"
        href={item.href}
        style={{ "text-decoration": "none" }}
        variants={{
          open: {
            y: "0%",
            opacity: 1,
            transition: { duration: 0.5 },
          },
          closed: {
            y: "25%",
            opacity: 0,
            transition: { duration: 0.5 },
          },
        }}
        whileHover={{
          scale: 1.2,
          transition: { duration: 0.1 },
        }}
      >
        {item.link}
      </motion.a>
    );
  })}
</motion.div>
```

I suspect it has to do with x and y positions, but i am totally lost here. The exit animation works fine, the only issue is `when: "afterChildren"` doesn't work on `exit="exit"`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).